# FindBugs: please build project before running sonar

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I am getting error

> ERROR: Caused by: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build
>   project before executing sonar and check the location of compiled
>   classes.

If I run `sonarrunner` with the SonarQube default profile for java "Sonar way" everything is fine but running using the new rules which contains `FindBugs` as repository key causes the issues.
I have also tried to use `sonar.binaries=folder` of the build classes 
but that is also not helping the issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this because I was running sonar:sonar before the install phase, and so the sources weren't compiled yet.  Running it after fixed it for me.